# Unselect effect Radio Material2 Angular 5

Tags: angular5, angular-material2

I'm using mat-radio-button(material2) and I have something like a quiz. When  I select an answer and go to the next quiz, the visual effect of unselect is showing in the second quiz. This happens if the selected option in the first quiz, appears in the second too, in the same position or after.

I made a simple example. You can reproduce it selecting "aa", then click ">>" button.

HTML

```
<mat-radio-group class="example-radio-group" [(ngModel)]="radioSelected">
    <mat-radio-button *ngFor="let option of tempSublist" [value]="option" class="example-radio-button" color="primary">
        {{option}}
    </mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
<hr>
<button (click)="prev()"><<</button>
<button (click)="next()">>></button>
```

Typescript

```
list = [
    ['aa','bb','cc'],
    ['cc','aa','bb'],
    ['bb','cc','ee'],
    ['dd','bb','cc'],
  ];
  index = 0;
  tempSublist = this.list[this.index];
  radioSelected:string;

  next(){
    if(this.index < this.list.length){
      this.radioSelected = null;
      this.index++;
      this.tempSublist = this.list[this.index];
    }
  }

  prev(){
    if(this.index >= 1){
      this.radioSelected = null;
      this.index--;
      this.tempSublist = this.list[this.index];
    }
  }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7s9qvs?file=app%2Fradio-ng-model-example.html

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding trackBy option on ngFor helps to reduce the transition between the two states. Also disabling repples with [disableRipple]="true" seems to reduce the visual effect:

**HTML**

```
<mat-radio-button [disableRipple]="true" *ngFor="let option of tempSublist;
                                                           trackBy: trackByFn" ...>
 ...
```

**Typescript**

```
next() {
if (this.index < this.list.length - 1) {
                         //add this ^
...

trackByFn(index, item) {
    return index; 
}
```

---

I thought adding a control on navigation buttons would be nice:

```
<button [disabled]="index <= 0" (click)="prev()"><<</button>
          ^- this
<button [disabled]="index === tempSublist.length" (click)="next()">>></button>
         ^- this
```

**[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7s9qvs-alaqvw)**

---

If this is not enough, in last recourse, hide and show the whole block.
Wrap it in a div and set ngIf:

```
<div *ngIf="isVisible">
    <mat-radio-group class="example-radio-group" [(ngModel)]="radioSelected">
...
```

and use timeout in the class on button click:

```
  next() {
    isVisible = true;

    this.isVisible = false;
    if (this.index < this.list.length - 1) {
     ...
    }
    setTimeout(() => this.isVisible = true, 30)
  }
```

**[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7s9qvs-fe9thq)**

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think this code works better than mine. But I would still like to avoid this visual effect of "unselecting".

Comment: I think it's a "natural" transition. It was selected, when the questions change it transitions with animation. I agree that in your version it's strange but in this version I don't see :)

Comment: Is this one better ? : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7s9qvs-pvmqgh

Comment: Did that help you?

Comment: No unfortunatelly. I was wondering if I can remove/hide the radio-group when I press "next", and then display it again to avoid this "transition".